# Reducing search impact on Windows 2008 file servers

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, network-share, search

Our file server (Windows 2008 R2) is using iSCSI volumes for storage. When someone searches for a file in one of the shared drives, it takes an awful amount of time before the results come up and of course, it also impacts the overall performance of the server.

I installed Windows Search Service on the server but searching on Windows 7 or XP is still slow. It's fast on the server though, probably because of the index. How do I make the Windows 7/XP workstations benefit from the Windows Search Service index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is for SBS 2008, but I think it can apply to your problem:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/sbs/archive/2010/04/05/find-items-faster-with-windows-search-and-libraries.aspx

Comment: After a few days of research, I realized that search can be further improved you add a solid-state drive to the server and use this as the location of the search index.